# Why requests calls for playlist.m3u8 / chunklist.m3u8 keep coming after stop playing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-live-streaming, m3u8

**I'm using Hls for streaming audio playlists with m3u8 format.** 
When I stop the music I run:
hls.stopLoad();
hls.detachMedia();

**But I still see requests** on network for the playlist/chunklist.

Is there a way to stop the requests other than refreshing/closing the window?

Comment: Are you using a library for HLS playback? What is `hls` in the context of calling `hls.stopLoad()`?

Comment: Try inspecting the code that's making the requests. You can do it by clicking on the initiator in devtools network panel.

Comment: HLS for streaming m3u8 typs of files - https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/.

Answer (score 0):

The player will continue to refresh until it encounters a ‘#EXT-X-ENDTAG’ in the playlist